# Парсинг определенных объектов с одинаковыми заголовками. Python

Tags: python, парсер, ссылки

начал изучать Python, и возник вопрос.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_="news_item lenta_item")
cards = []

for item in items:
    cards.append(
        {
            'title': item.find('span', class_= 'lenta_item_title').get_text(strip=True),
            'link': HOST + item.find('a').get('href'), #ПРОБЛЕМА ЗДЕСЬ
            'info': item.find('span', class_='lenta_textsmall').get_text(strip=True)
        }
    )
return cards
```

На сайте существует две ссылки, на новость и на раздел в которой она находится, как мне получать ссылку только с раздела. Ссылки находятся на разных уровнях кода.
[image: Скрин]

Можно ли как-то ограничить item.find только на один уровень 'news_item lenta_item'

Answer (score 0):

```
Попробуй так.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_="news_item lenta_item")
cards1 = []
for i in items:
    cards1.append(i[1])
cards = []

for cards1 in items:
    cards.append(
     {
        'title': item.find('span', 
class_='lenta_item_title').get_text(strip=True),
        'link': HOST + item.find('a').get('href'),  # ПРОБЛЕМА ЗДЕСЬ
        'info': item.find('span', class_='lenta_textsmall').get_text(strip=True)
    }
)
return cards
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]